# Help Identifying a component for PCB repair

Tags: diodes, identification, repair, component-selection

I'm helping a friend by attempting to repair this display PCB.  It uses 24vac input and he accidentally hooked it up to 120vac.

I am trying to identify the two components in this picture under the burn marks.  I'm pretty sure they are diodes but am looking for more specifics so that I can order replacements.  Anyone able to direct me anywhere or know anything about the two components labeled MX 21A.

[image]

Comment: My guess is way more then those are damaged if you hooked it into 120v

Comment: These were my thoughts exactly...but I told my friend I would try replacing those and see what happens.

Comment: There's several small traces running in between those diodes that got vaporized. The burnt spot might also have become partly conductive and need cutting a gap. If it's a multilayer board that'll get messy quick.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'l look out for this and check it out with my multimeter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MX is an SMD Code for TI's TVS protection diode that may withstand 48V

SMBJ48A   The left side, DS1 vaporized some material.